# How can I swap a file in and out of a directory, in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, script, autohotkey

My brother and I play this game on the same computer, but we have different in-game configs

Our in-game key binds and some other settings are different, and the game does *not* support separate configuration profiles.

In the past, we basically had to restore default > rebind our custom setting each time we swap places playing.

Recently, we started just manually swapping our individual game configs in and out of the game program files

Is there a program, script, or other means to make this change very easily? So we can just toggle between the two configs via a quick shortcut or something?

Comment: What's the name of the game? Also, where is the game config file stored? Do you have separate accounts?

Comment: The game is Heroes of Newerth, we have separate accounts, but that doesnt seem to be stored locally. (No user data or account directories) The file we swap out is called startup.cfg and it's in C:\Users\User\Documents\Heroes of Newerth\game

Comment: Launch the game and configure it the way you like, then exit. Make a copy of the `startup.cfg` file and rename it to `startup-yourName.cfg`. Logoff and let your brother do the same. You should end up with three copy of the `.cfg` file. At this point a script can be made to 1) replace the file before launching the game 2) launch the game 3) save the changes to the respective copy (so that the modified values can be loaded next time) when the game exits.

Comment: well we already have the 2 cfg files, I can just rename them whatever.. but yikes... I have no idea how to make a script like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch the game and configure it the way you like, then exit. Make a copy of the `startup.cfg` file and rename it to `startup-yourName.cfg`. Logoff and let your brother do the same. You should end up with three copy of the .cfg file. At this point a script can be made to:

1. Replace the file before launching the game.
2. Launch the game.
3. Save the changes to the respective copy (so that the modified values can be loaded next time) when the game exits.

### Example batch script

```
@echo off

set folder=C:\Users\User\Documents\Heroes of Newerth\game
set config=startup.cfg
set replacement=startup-yourName.cfg
set thegame=C:\Path\to\the\game.exe

copy /y "%folder%\%replacement%" "%folder%\%config%"
start "Heroes of Newerth" /wait "%thegame%"
copy /y "%folder%\%config%" "%folder%\%replacement%"

exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

simple solution, install the game 2 times in 2 separate folders, 99.9% of games allow you to do this without a problem.

Then create different shortcuts for you and your brother, the configurations will always be of those setting. UNLESS the game saves the configuration in a folder like my docs/games, if the the configuration files are stored locally in the installation, this should work.

downside, takes up more memory, but most computers now-a-days have super big hard drives, so i doubt this will be an issue.

edit: if your installation source detects there is already a copy of the game installed, then just copy your Game's installation folder to another place, and create the new shortcut. Because all a DISC data wise is literally copy the information of the game form the disc to your hard drive.